# Password protection for the lwIP telnet connection

Tags: udp, embedded, microcontroller, freertos, lwip

I would like to protect the lwIP implemented telnet connection through the password.
This is a legacy product, in this used STX91 with the FreeRTOS, able to send and receive telnet commands. Is there a way to implement password protection like SSH connection etc...?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet

Comment: telnet itself doesnt necessarily have authentication but when used as a transport the higher level may have a login prompt, etc.  you wont get ssh level with telnet you would need to implement ssh which creates a whole lot of new issues to solve.   create a login prompt and user/password or just password when the connection is made, at least for starters, whatever the telnet session connects to normally.